# Text Search on GAE Entities

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I implement text search facility on GAE Entities. 
I display the results to a cellTable with pages.
I use cursors to do the paging.
The issue I have is that when I search on 2 or more columns (properties) the cursor is lost
since the OR statement issues different queries and merges the results.

Any good ideas how to overcome this issue?
I do not want to use the Search API of GAE.